# How can I preserve the max screen resolution on my external monitor without inducing a magnification effect?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, hdmi

I have a new Dell Lattitude E6540 connected via HDMI to an Asus VH236HL. In both cases, the native resolution is 1920x1080, however the Dell has a 15.6" screen and the Asus has a 23" screen. As a result, if you drag any windows or content from the Dell to the Asus, there is a very conspicuous magnification effect.

Is there any way to eliminate this magnification jump between monitors?

Comment: You can downsize the resolution of the Asus screen... trial and error but it *may* work! Other than that, buying a new monitor at 23" (although that suggestion probably isn't very helpful)

Comment: To get the size of something composed of certain number of pixels to appear the same size on both screens, you'll have to change the resolution of at least one of them to something non-native so that the dpi on both is approximately the same.

Comment: Not really, you are essentially asking for a resize of the window you are dragging while you drag it. You can possibly mess around with some DPI settings but I guarantee you will do more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking for something impossible.  You cannot have both the max resolution and have the same sized pixels when the actual size of the pixels is different.

You can either:

1. Get two identical monitors.  Twice as much screen for only twice the price.
2. Reduce the resolution on the smaller screen to be closer in size to the other.
3. Make or find some hypothetical new operating system software that displays everything in physical sizes instead of pixels.